# How to put icons on both side of button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, icons

I need to put icons on both side of a text in a button like the image shown.

I have been trying to figure this out some time now, but cant seem to.

I saw the following example in Red-gate Mysql compare.

How can i fake or do this?

[image]

Comment: [Something like this](https://i.imgur.com/aEuSKcn.png)?

Comment: [Modified, because I decided to add it to the collection](https://i.imgur.com/nE9gWMn.gifv).

Comment: yes, something like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that's possible without creating a custom button and drawing the images yourself.

If you're looking for an easy workaround to "fake it", your best bet would be to use the [`BackgroundImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage) property instead of using `Image`:

- Create a transparent canvas with the same aspect ratio as your button.
- Add your two "icons" on it and align them to the left and right. It should look something like this:

  [image: Transparent canvas]
- Save the image as PNG and use it for the `BackgroundImage` property of the button.
- Set the [`BackgroundImageLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout) to `Zoom`<sup>1</sup>.
- You're good to go :)

**Here's the result:**

[image: Buttons]

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You can use `Stretch` instead if you don't want to worry about the aspect ratio, but that might not result in a nice looking image.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

A Custom Control which inherits the `Button` class (and [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged), I find it handy in many cases).

It adds some properties to the standard [Button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button) class:

**`public Image ImageLeft`**:  The left side Image.
**`public Image ImageRight`**:  The right side Image.

Can be both null (uses the default value).

**`public SizeMode ImageSizeMode`**:  Enumerator, selector for the drawing mode:

```
public enum SizeMode : int
{
    Stretch = 0,
    FixedSize,
    StretchMaxSize
}
```

**`public Size ImageFixedSize`**:  The images size when `SizeMode = FixedSize`.
The Images are always of the same custom size defined here.
**`public Size ImageMaxSize`**:  The images size when `SizeMode = StretchMaxSize`.
The Images size grows/shrink proportionally, but never beyond this size.

All drawings are made in the `OnPaint()` event dynamically (no hard-coded behaviours), so you can change it in whatever you want it to be.

See if you like it (change the `NameSpace` as needed).

[image]

The Images used here: [Left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pEWk.png) and [Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2hqL.png)

**As a note**, the Custom Control is detached from its specific Designer (that I can't post), so, when you change a graphics property, you have to click on the parent Form to see it applied. Add the Designer you like for these kind of objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class DoubleGButton : Button, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    Image m_ImageLeft = null;
    Image m_ImageRight = null;
    SizeMode m_ImageSizeMode = SizeMode.Stretch;
    Size m_ImageFixedSize = new Size(24, 24);
    Size m_ImageMaxSize = new Size(24, 24);

    public enum SizeMode : int
    {
        Stretch = 0,
        FixedSize,
        StretchMaxSize
    }

    public DoubleGButton() => InitializeComponent();

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        m_ImageLeft = default;
        m_ImageRight = default;
        base.MinimumSize = new Size(32, 24);
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    }

    public Image ImageLeft {
        get { return m_ImageLeft; }
        set { m_ImageLeft = value; Invalidate(); } }
    public Image ImageRight {
        get { return m_ImageRight; }
        set { m_ImageRight = value; Invalidate(); } }

    public SizeMode ImageSizeMode {
        get { return m_ImageSizeMode; }
        set { m_ImageSizeMode = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageSizeMode)); } }

    public Size ImageFixedSize {
        get { return m_ImageFixedSize; }
        set { m_ImageFixedSize = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageFixedSize)); } }

    public Size ImageMaxSize {
        get { return m_ImageMaxSize; }
        set { m_ImageMaxSize = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageMaxSize)); } }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        Invalidate();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        List<RectangleF> ImageBoxes = GetImageBoxes();
        if (m_ImageLeft != null) {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(ImageLeft, ImageBoxes[0]);
        }
        if (m_ImageRight != null) {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(ImageRight, ImageBoxes[1]);
        }
    }

    private List<RectangleF> GetImageBoxes()
    {
        var rects = new List<RectangleF>();
        var rectImageLeft = RectangleF.Empty;
        var rectImageRight = RectangleF.Empty;

        switch (ImageSizeMode)
        {
            case SizeMode.Stretch:
                rectImageLeft = new RectangleF(
                    new PointF(6, 6), 
                    new SizeF(Width / 10, Height - 12));
                rectImageRight = new RectangleF(
                    new PointF((Width - (Width / 10)) - 6, 6), 
                    new SizeF(Width / 10, Height - 12));
                break;
            case SizeMode.FixedSize:
                float TopPosition = (Height - ImageFixedSize.Height) / 2;
                rectImageLeft = new RectangleF(
                    new PointF(6, TopPosition), 
                    new SizeF(ImageFixedSize.Width, ImageFixedSize.Height));
                rectImageRight = new RectangleF(
                    new PointF(Width - ImageFixedSize.Width - 6, TopPosition), 
                    new SizeF(ImageFixedSize.Width, ImageFixedSize.Height));
                break;
            case SizeMode.StretchMaxSize:
                float BoxHeight = (Height - 12 > ImageMaxSize.Height) ? ImageMaxSize.Height : Height - 12;
                float TopBoxPosition = (Height - BoxHeight) / 2;
                float imageHeight = (BoxHeight > ImageMaxSize.Height) ? ImageMaxSize.Height : BoxHeight;
                float imageWidth = ImageLeft.Width / (ImageLeft.Height / imageHeight);
                imageWidth = (imageWidth > ImageMaxSize.Width) ? ImageLeft.Width : imageWidth;

                rectImageLeft = new RectangleF(
                    new PointF(6, TopBoxPosition), 
                    new SizeF(imageWidth, imageHeight));
                rectImageRight = new RectangleF(
                    new PointF(Width - imageWidth - 6, TopBoxPosition), 
                    new SizeF(imageWidth, imageHeight));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        rects.AddRange(new[] { rectImageLeft,  rectImageRight });
        return rects;
    }
}
```